# MediaWiki video extension with programmatic seeking

Tags: video, api, mediawiki

I would like to create a page on a MediaWiki wiki to instruct users how to complete a procedure using a piece of software.

Instead of taking lots of screenshots, I thought it would be better to have a list of written instructions on the left, then a video on the right. The list would have hyperlinks throughout, which when clicked would jump to & play a segment of the video pertaining to that step.

Could anyone suggest a MediaWiki extension which:

- Can play videos uploaded locally
- Has an API which allows it to seek and play a subset of the video

It would be nice if:

- It were possible for the user to make the video larger or smaller within the page
- It would sit within a floating division that would remain  stationary so the user could scroll down the list of instructions and still see the video
- It would transcode video behind the scenes (like TimedMediaHandler)

Though I am prepared I may need to make modifications to get the more advanced functionality.